# Why is chemical potential equivalent to a true potential?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, potential, terminology, chemical-potential

My K&K thermal physics testbook says chemical potential is equivalent to a true potential:

> the chemical potential is equivalent to a true potential energy: the difference in chemical potential between two systems is equal to the potential barrier that will bring the two systems into diffusive equilibrium.

However, I am very confused - since there is no conservative force generally, how come it is "equivalent" to a true potential?

We say "two are equivalent", usually when there is no experimental way to distinguish one from another. But surely there is: putting a test charge. Or is the book just saying *effectively/phenomenologically* their numerical values are equal? What exactly meant by saying these two are equivalent in the text?

---

I've checked Wiki: "Helmholtz free energy is the Legendre transformation of internal energy"; hence, Chemical potential is the change in Helmholtz free energy (some redefinition of internal energy) when we remove/add some particles. Given some conditions (e.g.two systems are connected), chemical potential (no conservative field at all, I think?) is equivalent to a real potential (with conservative field).

But I am not very certain if I do not misunderstand anything.

Answer (score 1):

Chemical potential is the difference in free energy to add a particle to the system. Consider two systems (1,2) with a contact with the reservoir at temperature $T$, then total free energy is
\begin{equation}
G = G_{1}+G_{2}
\end{equation}
But since the total number of particles is conserved
\begin{equation}
N = N_{1}+N_{2}
\end{equation}
Heltmholtz free energy will be minimum at equilibrium with respect to
$dN_{1}= -dN_{2}$. Then,
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial G}{\partial N} = \frac{\partial G_{1}}{\partial N_{1}}_{T,V}+\frac{\partial G_{2}}{\partial N_{2}}_{T,V} = 0.
\end{equation}
That means their chemical potential is same when there is no net particle exchange since

\begin{equation}
\mu_{1} = \mu_{2} \equiv \frac{\partial G_{1}}{\partial N_{1}}_{T,V} = \frac{\partial G_{2}}{\partial N_{2}}_{T,V}
\end{equation}
since $dN_{1}= -dN_{2}$. Therefore, chemical potential difference should indicate particle flow between two systems right? After all, when the difference is zero no net particle flows between them.
Now consider two systems with a different chemical potential. $\mu_{2}>\mu_{1}$ and temporarily block the diffusion between them. Now introduce a field between two systems so that system 1 particles have higher potential energy by an amount of $\delta\mu = \mu_{2}-\mu_{1}$. Therefore, we have basically increased the internal energy of the system 1, $U_{1}$ by  $\delta\mu$ amount right?.
Now, by our previous argument if we carry out the free energy calculation,$G = U-TS+PV$ stuff, we will find out their chemical potential would be same. That means even if we remove the blockage no net particle will flow. Therefore, do we achieve direct translation of potential energy difference with the chemical potential difference?

Comment: Thanks for answering! please correct me if I misunderstand you: basically you are saying 1.) there can be no conservative field (probably so, given ideal gas) 2.) however, we can see the gap between different chemical potentials as a "effective" field (but there is really no such a field - if we put one test charge in it, it will not tend to move in any particular direction, in our ideal gas case), as there exist a net particles flow?

Comment: I am trying to say if there exists a chemical potential difference between two systems, there will be net particle flow which will try increase the internal energy in the other side so that chemical potentials will be equalized to prevent further particle flow. This is equivalent to the particle moving in a potential.  I do not understand why you say, "when there is a chemical potential gap no net particle will flow", because there will be net flow. And I did not understand which conservative field are you refering in an ideal gas.

Comment: Sorry for your confusion, I mean : given there is a net particles flow, but in general there is no real electric potential field (say, given ideal gas), hence when we say "the chemical potential is equivalent to a true potential energy" we really just mean that phenomenologically.

Comment: My major confusion is: we say "equivalence", when there is no scientific way(no experimental way) to distinguish one from another. But surely there is: putting a test charge. So it is really juts "effectively"?

Comment: I think they represent the same quantity not ( effectively), chemical potential is macroscopic or statistical equivalent of the local potential.

Comment: Consider the following example, where two gases with different temperatures are connected each other via a tube. When the valve of the tube realesed there will be a net heat transfer from one side to other side because of the trmperature difference until the temperature is stabilized.

Comment: Now, you can look at the same system locally where molecules are colliding with each other randomly and at one sidd of the tube the molecules have higher average velocity but at each collision they transfer their energy. Locally what you observe will be there is an average potential difference due to the collisions which is identical with the macroscopic picture. Therefore, if you "measure" the local potential picture it will be identical with the chemical potential picture altough some there can be some local variations. Thus, their equivalence is experimental in that sense.

Comment: There are local electrical or other sort of fields indeed. In the case of ideal gase, the random collisions can be seen as local fields.

Comment: Sorry for my silence, I have been thinking this problem for days, chemical potential is really confusing me in many ways. Reply to the comments: but what if we assume in the ideal gas to be dilute (so that the ideal gas particles rarely hit each other)?